# ionic admob free run android no trabaja

Tags: ionic3, admob

cuando instalo admob free en ionic no corre.
error de play service.

no crea apk 
no ionic cordova run andorid.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/admob-free
```

.

```
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';


constructor(private admobFree: AdMobFree) { }


...


const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
 // add your config here
 // for the sake of this example we will just use the test config
 isTesting: true,
 autoShow: true
};
this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    // banner Ad is ready
    // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la respuesta.

estaba en una pagina de git  https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free/issues/141

solo cambie el .... playservice

**Riyaz0001** comentó 3 days ago • 
Cambio el archivo de **plataforma / proyecto.propiedades** , simplemente reemplace el número de versión y luego agregue el signo + .

Ejemplo: 
**antes**

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0
```

**Después**

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
```

y simplemente use este comando en CLI: cordova clean androidy compila de nuevo.

Espero resolver este problema para el complemento cordova-plugin-admob-free .